# What does “Save to my Dropbox” do?

Tags: dropbox

I have a link to another Dropbox folder and want to connect it to my Dropbox. The only real option I see available is *Download* → *Save to my Dropbox*.

When I select *Download* → *Save to my Dropbox*, is a copy being saved to my Dropbox or are the files linked to the original source? How will I know if the original source has been updated?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have just tried this using two separate Dropbox accounts to see the outcome, and I have found that it saves the file as a new file in the account. This is not linked at all to the previous file, as upon editing the original file, the file in my second account did not change.

The only way that I can see to find out if the source has been updated is by manually checking it.